# Conditional Standard Deviation Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to run a standard deviation formula on only a subset of a row. I have two conditions, the be below the top end of a range and above the bottom end of a range. Excel should the run STDEV formula on all numbers which meet this condition. I tried the following conditional array formula but consistently got the #Value error. Any suggestions?

The below formula was properly entered into excel as an array.

```
{=STDEV.P(IF(AND($V9:$V2000>($D$5*365-$D$7),$V9:$V2000<($D$5*365+$D$7)),$U$9:$U$2000,""))}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Ctrl-Shift-Enter after editing the formula instead of Enter to force it to be an array.  If done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Yes, I am entering the above formula as an array.

Comment: are there any errors in the data range or non-numerical characters?

Comment: I've never seen a function name with a `.` in the middle of it before.

Comment: Yes there are, but the AND() logic should kick them out. Furthermore STDEV.S ignores non numeric.

Comment: Array formulas do not like `AND` : `=STDEV.P(IF(($V9:$V2000>($D$5*365-$D$7))*($V9:$V2000<($D$5*365+$D$7)),$U$9:$U$2000,""))`

Comment: @MattCremeens this is correct syntax for new STDEV formulas .S/P in 2013 excel

Comment: @StuartAllan thanks! I just had never seen it before today.

Comment: @ScottCraner solved the problem! AND logic seemed to be the issue. Scott, please post an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I double checked that regarding AND logic in a non-array scenario. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It just takes me a minute to get the engines revved up.

Comment: Thanks again Scott, appreciate it! Everyone else, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Array formulas do not like the AND operator. A solution to the above formula is the following:

```
=STDEV.P(IF(($V9:$V2000>($D$5*365-$D$7))*($V9:$V2000<($D$5*365+$D$7)),$U$9:$U$2‌​000,""))
```